`NavigationSplitView` with `ZStack` in detail view causes `.sheet(item` to hang
I have a problem with a MacCatalyst app I build and run on MacOS 14.6 with XCode 16.4. The problem doesn't occur on MacOS 13.6 or iOS 16 or 17. In this app if I click a button to show a .sheet(item a few times (typically between 3 and 8 times) then the app starts consuming 100% CPU and the Spinning Wait Cursor shows. The cause of the issue is that my NavigationSplitView has a ZStack so that state is maintained for all panels, as recommended here and here. Minimum reproducible example is below. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to address this. This app must support MacOS 13.6 as well. Thank you!
import SwiftUI

enum Panel: Hashable {
    case panel
}    

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @State private var selection: Panel? = Panel.panel

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationSplitView {
                List(selection: $selection) {
                    NavigationLink(value: Panel.panel) {
                        Label("Panel", systemImage: "circle")
                    }
                }
            } detail: {
                ZStack { // this causes a crash on MacOS 14.6, but is required to maintain state
                    ContentView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PopupItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var popupItem : PopupItem?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            popupItem = PopupItem()
        } label: {
            Text("Show popup")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .sheet(item: $popupItem) { popupItem in
            DismissView()
        }
    }
}

struct DismissView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Button {
                dismiss()
            } label: {
                Text("Dismiss")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("Popup")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Is there any reason why dismissview contains a navigation stack and is not an alert view ?

Yes, in my real app dismissview is a complicated view that needs a toolbar. However i reduced the code to an MRE. Thank you

Not sure but it seems to be related to a Mac Catalyst bug

This issue seems to arise when a .sheet is shown within a second of another sheet being dismiss()ed. Here is a workaround I experimented with that seems annoying to implement throughout a complex application. I am still seeking a better solution.
This solution tracks the time a sheet is dismissed in an app level state. Then if a sheet is opened within 1.5 seconds it defers the opening of the sheet until 1.5 seconds has elapsed. 1 second is too short because the app will still hang. 2 seconds is too long because the app segfaults.
import SwiftUI

enum Panel: Hashable {
    case activities
}

class SheetManager : ObservableObject {
    var lastTime = DispatchTime.now()
    var waiting = false
    
    public func onDismiss() {
        lastTime = DispatchTime.now()
        print("dismiss \(lastTime)")
    }
    
    public func waitToShow(_ showSheet: @escaping () -> ()) {
        if waiting {
            print("show ignore click")
            return
        }
        let nextTime = lastTime + 1.5
        let now = DispatchTime.now()
        if nextTime > now {
            waiting = true
            print("show wait next \(nextTime) last \(lastTime) now \(now)")
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: nextTime) {
                self.waiting = false
                self.lastTime = DispatchTime.now()
                print("show deferred now \(self.lastTime)")
                showSheet()
            }
        } else {
            print("show next \(nextTime) last \(lastTime)")
            lastTime = DispatchTime.now()
            showSheet()
        }
    }
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject private var sheetManager = SheetManager()
    @State private var selection: Panel? = Panel.activities

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationSplitView {
                List(selection: $selection) {
                    NavigationLink(value: Panel.activities) {
                        Label("Panel", systemImage: "circle")
                    }
                }
            } detail: {
                ZStack { // this causes a crash on MacOS
                    ContentView()
                }
            }
            .environmentObject(sheetManager)
        }
    }
}

struct PopupItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sheetManager: SheetManager
    @State var popupItem : PopupItem?
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            sheetManager.waitToShow {
                popupItem = PopupItem()
            }
        } label: {
            Text("Show popup")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .sheet(item: $popupItem) { popupItem in
            DismissView()
        }
    }
}

struct DismissView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sheetManager: SheetManager
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button {
                sheetManager.onDismiss()
                dismiss()
            } label: {
                Text("Dismiss")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("Popup")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

